# How can I style the output of an array?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I style the data returned from this array to separate the main category from the subcategories?

This is the code with which I extract the data from the database:

```
function fetchCategoryTree($parent = 0, $spacing = '', $user_tree_array = '') {

        if (!is_array($user_tree_array))
            $user_tree_array = array();

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `products_category_translate` WHERE `parentID` = $parent AND `language` = 'bg'";
            $query = mysqli_query($sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($query)) {
                $user_tree_array[] = array("id" => $row->id, "uniqueID" => $row->uniqueID, "title" => $spacing . $row->title);
                $user_tree_array = fetchCategoryTree($row->uniqueID, $spacing . '-- ', $user_tree_array);
            }
        }
        return $user_tree_array;
    }
```

The code with which I output the fetchCategoryTree () result:

```
$categoryList = fetchCategoryTree();
foreach($categoryList as $cl) { 
echo '<a href="'.$g['url'].''.languageURL('0', 'products/'.$cl['uniqueID'].'/'.convertToURL($cl['title']).'.html').'">'.$cl['title'].'</a><br>';
}
```

Recording the categories and subcategories of the database:

```
(id, uniqueID, title, language, parentID)
(1, 1, 'cat1', 'en', 0, 0),
(2, 2, 'subcat1', 'en', 0, 1),
```

I try to extract the data as follows:

```
<li>category
<ul><li>subcategory</li></ul>
</li>
```

Comment: @B001ᛦ Hi, I've updated my post. I hope now it is clear what I am trying to achieve.
In a nutshell: tree structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem or complication in your code when you assign to `$user_tree_array`.
The following code tries to work around that, but is in no way perfect.

```
function fetchCategoryTree($parent = 0, $spacing = '', $depth = 0) {

    $user_tree_array = array();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `products_category_translate` WHERE `parentID` = $parent AND `language` = 'bg'";
    $query = mysqli_query($sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($query)) {
            $child = array("id" => $row->id, "uniqueID" => $row->uniqueID, "title" => $spacing . $row->title, "depth"=>$depth, "sub_categories" => array());
            $child ["sub_categories"] = fetchCategoryTree($row->uniqueID, $spacing . '-- ', $depth+1);
            $user_tree_array[] = $child;
        }
    }
    return $user_tree_array;
}

function print_recursive($categoryList) {
    if(empty($categoryList)) {
        return;
    }
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($categoryList as $cl) { 
        echo "<li>";
        echo '<a href="'.$g['url'].''.languageURL('0', 'products/'.$cl['uniqueID'].'/'.convertToURL($cl['title']).'.html').'">'.$cl['title'].'</a>';
        print_recursive($cl["sub_categories"]]; 
        echo "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}   

$categoryList = fetchCategoryTree();
print_recursive($categoryList);
```

Comment: Thank you ! 
With this method, I can only identify the main categories. How can I list sub categories as list style as well ?

Comment: Well I added the depth parameter to help with that. Let me edit my code to show how to process the array recursively.

Comment: Thank you ! This will certainly be helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

You should change the approach for it. First you need to make a multidimensional array which should be contain their child inside a sub array.
So in that case you can run loop inside a loop to print it in recursive`<li>` (list) elements.
That will solve your problem.

Comment: This is the best way to solve the problem but answer should contain more explanation than that - maybe add example or at least pseudo code explaining this